# Parsing timestamp Soap fied to Java Date

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, soap, timestamp

I received from a SOAP message the follow date: 
**2012-11-16T02:02:05Z**

How to parse to Date? What means this T and the Z in the date according with the SOAP specification?

Comment: Take a look at the SimpleDateFormat class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html to understand the meaning of those. They are not specific to SOAP, btw.

Comment: @Vikdor wow, not specific to SOAP but there is some example. It seems the chars T and Z does not meaning anything according the example I found there: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Comment: Just Z seems to be the timezone, but The value is comming from paypal webservice is not according the specification..

Comment: Similar: [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2201925/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can parse correctly doing this way:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(paymentDate);
```

Thanks @vikdor!

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2012-11-16T02:02:05Z" )
```

## ISO 8601

Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. That standard defines many useful, practical, unambiguous textual formats for representing date-time values.

The ISO 8601 formats are commonly adopted by modern protocols, such as XML schema, SOAP, etc., supplanting the clumsy outmoded formats such as [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) / RFC 822.

Your particular format from ISO 8601 uses:

- `T` to separate the year-month-day portion from the hour-minute-second portion.
- `Z`, short for `Zulu`, to indicate [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time (an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of `+00:00`).

## Using java.time

Use the modern classes in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package. They use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2012-11-16T02:02:05Z" ) ;
```

Capture the current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Generate a string in standard format by simply calling `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2017-07-26T01:23:45.704781401Z

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
- See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).